specializing a member function which has an independent template parameter
I am trying to extend and specialize a member function of the BitStream class from rapidCheck.
template <typename Source>
class BitStream {
public:
  explicit BitStream(Source source);

  /// Returns the next value of the given type with maximum size.
  template <typename T>
  constexpr T next();

  constexpr char next();
};

template <typename Source>
BitStream<Source>::BitStream(Source source)
{}

template <typename Source>
template <typename T>
constexpr T BitStream<Source>::next() {
  return T();
}

template <typename Source>
constexpr char BitStream<Source>::next() { return (char)(1); }

int main() {
    BitStream<int> bs(2);
    static_assert( bs.next<int>() == 0 ); // as expected
    static_assert( bs.next() == 1 );      // not really a specialization
    static_assert( bs.next<char>() == 1 ); // fails, but this should succeed!
}

This simplified snippet compiles, but the last assert fails, since I had not been able to really specialize next() for T=char. How could that be achieved?
My requirement here is that I want to be compatible to the rest of rapidcheck, so bs.next<char>() should call the specialized version.
Thanks in advance!

Why do you have a non-template overload of next?

You cannot specialize a member template of an unspecialized class template.

@273K: I just don't know how to implement the missing pieces, so that a specialization is declared and defined and then hopefully used. Currently my test fails, because it uses the generic version (which is the only one existing right now).

@DavisHerring: At first, I was toying around first with syntax, when it compiled I added the asserts and found, I had implemented an next() overload instead of a specialization... Sorry for the confusion!

@n.m.couldbeanAI: Ok, so how could this class template be specialized then in order to specialize the member function template?

The answer shows how to do that.

You could somewhat "partially specialize" your method with using if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, char>) { return (char)(1); }.

You may only specialize a member template in a specialized class template like in the following reduced example:
template <typename Source>
class BitStream {
 public:
  explicit BitStream(Source source);

  /// Returns the next value of the given type with maximum size.
  template <typename T>
  constexpr T next();
};

template <>
template <>
constexpr char BitStream<int>::next<char>() {
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  BitStream<int> bs(2);
  static_assert(bs.next<char>() == 1);  // succeeds
}

Suggestion. Consider implementing a custom std::basic_streambuf instead of BitStream and you will be able to use input streams and input operators like bs >> char_var and bs >> int_var instead of char_var = bs.next<char>() and int_var = bs.next<int>().

Thanks for helping me out, and I will surely meditate over your suggestion.
